# Eclipse can't find RemoteControlClient for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to do the example code in `sdk/samples/android-14/RandomMusicPlayer`, but when I imported the project into Eclipse, it is having problems finding RemoteControlClient.

I'm not sure why this is. I went into my `sdk/sources/android-14/android/media` folder, and sure enough it's there, but after I imported the project I have an error in MusicService.java saying "The import android.media.RemoteControlClient cannot be resolved"

Does anyone have any ideas?